# Sending mail via android application

Tags: java, android, email

I am trying to make an app on Android which can send an email. I tried to find an answer, but nothing. The problem is that in this code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
WebView wv;
EditText edt1;
EditText edt2;

ProgressDialog pdialog;
Context context = null;
Session session;
String email;
String sprava;
String emailTo = "chief@gmail.com";
String subject;
String user;
String pass;
Button clickButton;
StringBuilder celyEmail = new StringBuilder();
String rec;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    try {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        context = this;


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity2.this);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        clickButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("mojachyba",e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(et1);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(et2);
    email = edt1.getText().toString();
    sprava = edt2.getText().toString();
    subject = "Mail z aplikacie";
    user = "user@gmail.com";
    pass = "rainy";

    celyEmail.append("Mail od: ");
    celyEmail.append(email);
    celyEmail.append('\n');
    celyEmail.append('\n');
    celyEmail.append("Správa: ");
    celyEmail.append(sprava);


    Properties props = new Properties();
    Authenticator authh = new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
        }
    };
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    session = Session.getInstance(props, authh);

    pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"","Posielam mail...",true);
    RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
    task.execute();
}


class  RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailTo));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(celyEmail, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

            Transport.send(message);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        pdialog.dismiss();
        edt1.setText("");
        edt2.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"E-mail odoslaný", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public static boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id2 = item.getItemId();

    if (id2 == R.id.nav_domov) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("website","http://lodkanadeje.maweb.eu/");
        MainActivity2.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else if (id2 == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("website","http://lodkanadeje.rajce.idnes.cz/");
        MainActivity2.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    } else if (id2 == R.id.nav_facebook) {
        SharingToSocialMedia("com.facebook.katana");
    } else if (id2 == R.id.nav_twitter) {
        SharingToSocialMedia("com.twitter.android");
    } else if (id2 == R.id.nav_mail){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity2.class);
        MainActivity2.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
public void SharingToSocialMedia(String application) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.google.sk/");

    boolean installed = checkAppInstall(application);
    if (installed) {
        intent.setPackage(application);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Nie je nainštalovaná aplikácia", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
private boolean checkAppInstall(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
  }
```

After about debug I found out that the app is crashing at the line

`session = Session.getInstance(props, authh);`

and i have no idea why. My exception:

```
05-10 18:41:16.124 4199-4199/eu.maweb.lodkanadeje.lodkanadeje E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: eu.maweb.lodkanadeje.lodkanadeje, PID: 4199
                                                                            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;
                                                                                at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:226)
                                                                                at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
                                                                                at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:247)
                                                                                at eu.maweb.lodkanadeje.lodkanadeje.MainActivity2.onClick(MainActivity2.java:162)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
```

Comment: you can follow this https://github.com/anik123/Send-Email-from-App-Silently

Comment: don't you consider calling a mail app via intent?

Comment: @nandsito When I use intent the app asks for email provider or sending app... I want to make it without user interaction